# Method that expands into <li>...</li> expression

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, refactoring

Let's suppose I have the following in a 'cshtml' file:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
</li>
```

I'd like to setup a method `Link` so that I can do the following instead of the above:

```
@Link("nav-link text-white", "Home", "Index", "Home")
@Link("nav-link text-white", "Home", "Privacy", "Privacy")
```

Here's one approach that I tried:

```
@{
    void Link(string a_class, string controller, string action, string text)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="@a_class" asp-area="" asp-controller="@controller" asp-action="@action">@text</a>
        </li>
    }

}
```

However, this leads the following error message:

[image]

What's a good way to implement the above `Link` method?

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume you want to achieve reusablility. If thats the case then you will have a better option of creating a partial view for that

this will be your partial view

```
@model MyPartialModel
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="@Model.Class" asp-area="@Model.Area" asp-controller="@Model.Controller" asp-action="@Model.Action">@Model.Text</a>
</li>

//Then you can call it anywhere
@await Html.PartialAsync("NameOfFile", new { Text ="whatever" Controller="MyController" Action=MyAction" className ="the-class"})
//Or even replace the anonymous object with a model rather
```

And.....that's it

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion!

I would still however like to see if there's an approach close to what I demonstrate in the question. I.e. a way to have something like a helper defined in a code block inside that file.

Comment: Is there any difference with what you want and what I've presented in a better way?

Comment: I added an answer that finally solves the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar example from Razor Pages instead of MVC.

The following:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/About">About</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Students/Index">Students</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Courses/Index">Courses</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Instructors/Index">Instructors</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Departments/Index">Departments</a>
</li>
```

can be replaced with:

```
@{ 
    await Template("/About",             "About");
    await Template("/Students/Index",    "Students");
    await Template("/Courses/Index",     "Courses");
    await Template("/Instructors/Index", "Instructors");
    await Template("/Departments/Index", "Departments");

}
```

given the following at the beginning of the Razor file:

```
@{ 
    async Task Template(string asp_page, string text)
    { 
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="@asp_page">
                @text
            </a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's an example which shows how to factor out a tag-helper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67657283/268581