# Partial that expands into input tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, refactoring

The book *Pro ASP.NET Core 3* has the [the following code](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/27%20-%20Using%20the%20Forms%20Tag%20Helpers/End%20of%20Chapter/WebApp/Pages/FormHandler.cshtml#L6-L30) in its example for chapter 27:

```
<div class="m-2">
    <h5 class="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">HTML Form</h5>
    <form asp-page="FormHandler" method="post" id="htmlform">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Price" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Category.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Supplier</label>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Supplier.Name" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <button form="htmlform" asp-page="FormHandler" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">
        Sumit (Outside Form)
    </button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `<div class="form-group>...</div>` pattern is repeated four times. As a test of partials, I added the file `Pages\_FormGroupPartial.cshtml`:

```
@model FormGroupParams

<div class="form-group">
    <label>@Model.LabelContent</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ForString" />
</div>
```

In `Pages\FormHandler.cshtml.cs` I added the following class:

```
public class FormGroupParams
{        
    public string LabelContent;
    public string ForString;

    public FormGroupParams(string labelContent, string forString)
    {
        LabelContent = labelContent;
        ForString = forString;
    }
}
```

To test this out, I edited `Pages\FormHandler.cshtml` to use the new partial right after the original approach:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Supplier.Name" />
</div>

<partial name="_FormGroupPartial" model='new FormGroupParams("Supplier", "Product.Supplier.Name")' />
```

In the resulting page, we see that the partial did not quite generate the same code; note that the value is now `Product.Supplier.Name` instead of the expected `Splash Dudes`:

[image]

Looking at the source, we see that the original code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Supplier.Name" />
</div>
```

expanded into:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Product_Supplier_Name" name="Product.Supplier.Name" value="Splash Dudes" />
</div>
```

Whereas our partial:

```
<partial name="_FormGroupPartial" model='new FormGroupParams("Supplier", "Product.Supplier.Name")' />
```

expanded into:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ForString" name="ForString" value="Product.Supplier.Name" />
</div>
```

Is there a good way to implement this partial so as to get the same output as the original code?

---

**UPDATE 2020-09-30**

PeterG suggests the following in his answer below:

```
<partial name="_FormGroupPartial" model='new FormGroupParams("Supplier", @Model.Product.Supplier.Name)' />
```

This expands into the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ForString" name="ForString" value="Splash Dudes" />
</div>
```

whereas the goal is the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Product_Supplier_Name" name="Product.Supplier.Name" value="Splash Dudes" />
</div>
```

So the `value` is now correct. But the `id` and `name` are still off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the book, Adam Freeman, has provided an example to me via email which demonstrates solving this using a tag helper.

Add the file `TagHelpers/FormGroupTagHelper.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

namespace WebApp.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("form-group")]
    public class FormGroupTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "div";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "form-group");

            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.InnerHtml.Append(Label ?? For.Name);
                        
            var input = new TagBuilder("input");
            input.AddCssClass("form-control");
            input.Attributes["type"] = "text";
            input.Attributes["id"] = For.Name.Replace(".", "_");
            input.Attributes["name"] = For.Name;
            input.Attributes["value"] = For.Model.ToString();
            
            output.Content.AppendHtml(label);
            output.Content.AppendHtml(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in `Pages/FormHandler.cshtml` instead of this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Supplier.Name" />
</div>
```

you can use the following:

```
<form-group label="Supplier" for="Product.Supplier.Name"/>
```

Thanks Adam!

Comment: a big +1 for including the `using` statements! I hate always having to guess or lookup all the libraries

Answer (score 1):

It will be very complex to bind a varibale to input tag helper and make it be recognized as the corresponding model field.

This will involve the source code of the input tag helper, and consider different types of input.

What I suggest is to **directly add the name and id attributes after asp-for in the partial view to overwrite the original generation**.

You only need to pass an extra value parameter when calling the partial view：

Here is the code:

Pages\FormHandler.cshtml:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Supplier.Name" />
</div>

          <partial name="_FormGroupPartial" 
    model='new FormGroupParams("Supplier","Product.Supplier.Name", @Model.Product.Supplier.Name)' />
```

Pages\FormHandler.cshtml.cs:

```
 public class FormGroupParams
    {
        public string LabelContent;
        public string ForString;
        public string Value;
        public FormGroupParams(string labelContent, string forString, string value)
        {
            LabelContent = labelContent;
            ForString = forString;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Pages_FormGroupPartial.cshtml:

```
@model FormGroupParams

<div class="form-group">
    <label>@Model.LabelContent</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Value" id="@Model.ForString.Replace(".","_")" name="@Model.ForString"  />
</div>
```

Here is the rendered html :

[image]

Comment: Yongqing Yu, you're right, this can be done with a tag helper. I added an answer below demonstrating this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by passing "Product.Supplier.Name" as the string value into your FormGroupParams object for the partial model. Instead you need to pass the actual value of the Product.Supplier.Name property from the model.

Something like this maybe:

```
<partial name="_FormGroupPartial" model='new FormGroupParams("Supplier", @Model.Product.Supplier.Name)' />
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion PeterG. I've updated my question demonstrating your suggestion.

Comment: Apologies I hadn't noticed the ID and Name issue. This answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150252/10070561) provided by @yongqing-yu should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach which uses a template function instead of a partial.

The following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Price" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Category</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Category.Name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Supplier</label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Product.Supplier.Name" />
</div>
```

can be replaced with:

```
@{ 
    await Template("Name",     "Product.Name");
    await Template("Price",    "Product.Price");
    await Template("Category", "Product.Category.Name");
    await Template("Supplier", "Product.Supplier.Name");
}
```

given the following template function at the beginning of the Razor page:

```
@{ 
    async Task Template(string label, string str)
    {
        var expr = Model.CreateModelExpression(str);

        <div class="form-group">

            <label>@label</label>

            <input class="form-control" asp-for="@expr.Model" />

        </div>
    }
}
```

The `CreateModelExpression` method referenced there is defined in the page model:

```
public class FormHandlerModel : PageModel
{
    private ModelExpressionProvider _modelExpressionProvider { get; set; }

    private DataContext context;

    public FormHandlerModel(DataContext dbContext, ModelExpressionProvider modelExpressionProvider)
    {
        context = dbContext;
        _modelExpressionProvider = modelExpressionProvider;
    }

    public ModelExpression CreateModelExpression(string expr)
    {
        var dict = new ViewDataDictionary<FormHandlerModel>(ViewData);
        
        return _modelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(dict, expr);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Note that a `ModelExpressionProvider` is brought in via dependency-injection.

The above Razor page on github: [link](https://github.com/dharmatech/TagHelperTemplateExample/blob/2021-05-23-01-form-handler-template-refactored/Pages/FormHandler.cshtml).

The above page model on github: [link](https://github.com/dharmatech/TagHelperTemplateExample/blob/2021-05-23-01-form-handler-template-refactored/Pages/FormHandler.cshtml.cs).

Suggestions on how to improve this are welcome!