# Factoring out markup in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

## Repeated code

In my application, I had code like this that was repeated in a bunch of places:

```
@if (economy.Cash == economy_base.Cash)
{
    <span>
        "Cash" @(String.Format("{0:N2}", economy.Cash))
    </span>
}
else
{
    <span>
        Cash @(String.Format("{0:N2}", economy_base.Cash))
        <span style="color: purple;">
            (@(String.Format("{0:N2}", economy.Cash)))
        </span>
    </span>    
}
```

where `economy.Cash`, `economy_base.Cash` and `"Cash"` were values that were different in each case.

## Factoring it out into a function

At first, I looked into using the technique described here that works for ASP.NET Core applications:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67656536/268581

However, the exact approach there didn't seem to work in Blazor.

So instead of using a function signature of `async Task Template(...)` I used `void Template(...)`. And this seems to have worked!

Given this:

```
@{
    void Template(string label, decimal? a, decimal? b)
    {
        @if (a == b)
        {
            <span>
                @label @(String.Format("{0:N2}", a))
            </span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>
                @label @(String.Format("{0:N2}", b))
                <span style="color: purple;">
                    (@(String.Format("{0:N2}", a)))
                </span>
            </span>    
        }
    }
}
```

I can use the following:

```
@{
    Template("Cash", economy.Cash, economy_base.Cash);
}
```

and it'll expand into the example code shown above in the first section.

## Question

When defining `Template` I just took a wild guess and tried the `void Template(...)` signature.

My question is, is this a valid and recommended way to factor out Blazor markup into a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer deleted - not worth of being accepted...

> My question is, is this a valid and recommended way to factor out Blazor markup into a function?

This may be a valid way to do that, but it is not the way things are done in Blazor. The recommanded way or rather a good practice is to use the RenderFragment delegate type, which was invented to render partial markup...

There are plenty of ways to implement your function... Here's one:

Copy and test...

```
@page "/"

@Template(("my label", valA, valB))

@code
{
    decimal? valA = 2.34M;
    decimal? valB = 3.34M;

    private RenderFragment<(string label, decimal? a, decimal? b)> Template => value => __builder =>
    {
        @if (@value.a == @value.b)
        {
        <span>
            @value.label @(String.Format("{0:N2}", @value.a))
        </span>
        }
        else
        {
        <span>
            @value.label @(String.Format("{0:N2}", @value.b))
            <span style="color: purple;">
                (@(String.Format("{0:N2}", @value.a)))
            </span>
        </span>
        }
    };
}
```

Note: It is a good practice to use the RenderFragment delegate in place of Rqazor components. Thus, and solution to implement your code through components is a very bad thing to do. Components are very expensive, and must not be used for the sole purpose of rendering content.

Another way, often preferable to other approaches is the use of [Templated Razor delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#templated-razor-delegates)

```
@page "/"

@Template(values)

@code
    {
   
    private RenderFragment<MyClass> Template = (values) =>@<p>
    @if (@values.valA == @values.valB)
    {
        <span>
            @values.Label @(String.Format("{0:N2}", @values.valA))
        </span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span>
            @values.Label @(String.Format("{0:N2}", @values.valB))
            <span style="color: purple;">
                (@(String.Format("{0:N2}", @values.valA)))
            </span>
        </span>
    }
</p>;

    private MyClass values = new MyClass { Label = "my label", valA = 2.34M, valB = 3.34M };

    private class MyClass
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public decimal? valA { get; set; }
        public decimal? valB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you.

Comment: Besides being unconventional, I wonder if there are any technical downsides to using the function approach I demonstrated?

Comment: `technical downsides,`  Not that I'm aware of (referring to your code). But this is the Blazor way to render markup. I guess that in complex usages you'll need to use the RenderFragment delegate, as for instance, when the parameters themselves are RenderFragment delegates.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is this a valid and recommended way to factor out Blazor markup into a function?

There is nothing inherently wrong with it, but be aware that this is not a normal Template.

What you have here is a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) inside the `override BuildRenderTree()` that is generated from the markup section. Hence the need to surround the calls with `@ { }`.

Your other options are

- a `RenderFragment<T> Template`, but that would require that you bundle `string label, decimal? a, decimal? b` into one Type somehow.
  Usage `@Template(new MyType("Cash", economy.Cash, economy_base.Cash))`, without  extra `@{}`
- a normal Blazor Component (separate .razor file).
  Usage would look like `<Template Label="Cash" A="economy.Cash" B="economy_base.Cash" />`

Comment: It seems like the RenderFragment and component approaches are more complex than the simple approach I used. I wonder if there are any downsides to the function approach?

Comment: The local function approach reduces readability - you wouldn't want to scale that up to many more or much larger templates. I always try to keep the markup section as clean as possible.

Comment: Can't `T` just be a tuple?